# Nonce doesn't validate in nopriv call

Tags: ajax, nonce

I have a function which uses Ajax calls:

```
function bs_reserve_gift()
{
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['_wpnonce'], 'reserve_gift')) {
        $response['status'] = 'error';
        $response['message'] = __('Something went wrong, please try again later!', 'bs');
        echo json_encode($response);
        exit();

    } else {
        update_post_meta($_POST['reserve_gift_id'], 'gift_status', 'reserved');
        $response['status'] = 'success';
        $response['gift_id'] = $_POST['reserve_gift_id'];
        $response['message'] = __('Thank you, the gift was reserved for you!', 'bs');
        echo json_encode($response);
        exit();

    }

}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_reserve_gift', 'bs_reserve_gift');
add_action('wp_ajax_reserve_gift', 'bs_reserve_gift');
```

This works for logged in users, but for non logged users the nonce doesn't validate for some reason...

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use check_ajax_referer:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/check_ajax_referer

```
//Check nonce
if ( !check_ajax_referer( 'nonce-action-name', '_wpnonce', false ) ){
    echo __('Ajax Security Check', 'yourtextdomain');
    die();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but I'm still curious why the wp_verify_nonce doesn't work...